# SML - Unzip tuples in one list

Tags: list, tuples, sml, unzip

I need to "unzip" a list of tuples and even though I tried with the `unzip` function it doesn't do what I want to. In fact, as I understood the `unzip` function returns you a tuple of list, but what i want is this.

Giving a list of tuple like this:

```
L1 = [(("s0","l0"),("l0","s1")),(("s1","l1"),("l1","s2"))]
```

of type:

```
(string*string)*(string*string) list
```

the function should return me a single list composed by the unzipped tuples:

```
L2 = [("s0","l0"),("l0","s1"),("s1","l1"),("l1","s2")]
```

of type:

```
(string*string) list
```

The only solution I found is:

```
fun f(h as (x,y,z),nil) =  [(x,x^y^z)]@[(x^y^z,z)]
|f (h as (x,y,z),t::rest) = 
    let val i = ref 0
        in if !i=0 then (i := !i+1; (x,x^y^z)::f(h,t::rest)) else (i := !i-1;(x^y^z,z)::f(t,rest)) end;
```

and I thought it could work but when I run the function the system crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what the function you posted does, but it almost certainly won't unzip a list of 2-tuples for you. It seems to expect 3-tuples, and does some de-referencing/concatenation to boot. How did you find it?

If you want a function that takes a list of 2-tuples and returns a list of their elements, you can do

```
fun peel lst =
    let fun recur [] acc = List.rev acc
      | recur ((a, b)::rest) acc = 
        recur rest (b::a::acc)
    in 
    recur lst []
    end
```

that is, go through the list, collecting both elements of each tuple, and return the reverse of your accumulator when you get to the end.

```
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.76 [built: Thu Feb 19 00:37:13 2015]
- fun peel lst =
    let fun recur [] acc = List.rev acc
      | recur ((a, b)::rest) acc = 
        recur rest (b::a::acc)
    in 
    recur lst []
    end ;;
= = = = = = [autoloading]
[library $SMLNJ-BASIS/basis.cm is stable]
[autoloading done]
val peel = fn : ('a * 'a) list -> 'a list
- peel [(("s0","l0"),("l0","s1")),(("s1","l1"),("l1","s2"))] ;;
val it = [("s0","l0"),("l0","s1"),("s1","l1"),("l1","s2")]
  : (string * string) list
-
```

Because of the way its defined, it has the (possibly unnecessary bonus) that it can similarly process any list of 2-tuples.

```
- peel (peel [(("s0","l0"),("l0","s1")),(("s1","l1"),("l1","s2"))]) ;;
val it = ["s0","l0","l0","s1","s1","l1","l1","s2"] : string list
-
```